# get total no of attached media to a specific post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, media, posts

I want to display all attached media to a specific post in a slider, so I want the total count of attached media to a specific post. example I want to display as 1/5 2/5 and so on. for each post?
so how to get the total count?
and as well as increment the counter according.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do the trick

```
  sizeof(get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id ) )
```

Check the link below

[get_attached_media](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`get_attached_media`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) function. That function returns an array with all the attached media for a given post, the length of the array would be the total count.

Can you add the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

```
$attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID ) );
$count = count( $attachments );
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20731/how-to-count-media-attachments